# Spring oscillation model

Tags: rotational-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, vibrations

When a spring - in real world - is extended $Xo$ from its natural position, it oscillates and eventually decreasing it's amplitude with time, comes to a stop. Is this a damped system or no? **If yes how can I calculate the ζ value and the damping coefficient of a given spring?**

Comment: This is a standard student laboratory experiment which is described many times in textbooks and on the Internet.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-5oq-igwtU  However, I do not understand what your $\zeta$ value is and why you like to *calculate* the damping coefficient. As I see it, the damping coefficient is *not* a characteristic quantity of the spring, but rather a quantity describing the interaction between the spring and the environment. Could you please clarify this.

Comment: I agree, and that's exactly why I am asking. How can  we evaluate the interaction of spring with the environment in theory (let's say without air resistance). Is this a case of damped oscillation?-since it eventually come to an end is not harmonic.